# Umbraco angular errors

Tags: angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

We have a project running Umbraco 7.5.9

We have suddenly started to get the following errors when loading Umbraco and opening various document types

```
Failed to load template: views/components/umb-folder-grid.html?umb__rnd=7.5.9.884162080
```

The errors come from `/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js`

Is this a server setting that is causing this? The error has suddenly started appearing in several applications

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your project path whether `Umbraco\Views\components\umb-folder-grid.html` files exist?

It seems like you are missing that file - maybe accident delete it or did not include it when publish

Comment: No, that file does exist in my project

Comment: when you say in the project do you mean from VS or the windows explorer? It may sound stupid but just make sure the physical path exist. from what I known about umbraco, there is nothing in setting which affect  umb-folder-grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your dev tools network tab and look for the call for the `umb-folder-grid.html` file.

It should come with a 200 response, but in your instance it may be 404ing.

I found that this file is requested when I go to the Media section of Umbraco.

If the file is 404ing, open up the location of the file in a separate tab and see if anything is being returned. If there is nothing there, check that your server does have the file on it.

[image]